# Can't insert data in google sheets from android app (Java)

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, android-volley

I'm trying to insert a data on google sheet api by calling this method on my code. but it's not working, what is wrong with my code?

```
public  void   addItemToSheet() {
    
            //final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Adding Item","Please wait");
            String code = "insert test";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwvCuLeJpsH6iQ6UojH5tR4rLQW98JFjVa0DqOujqb1Krox_mhbdrb9DRljMMOrsoGk/exec",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                           // loading.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();
                    //here we pass params
                    parmas.put("Code",code);
    
                    return parmas;
                }
            };
    
            int socketTimeOut = 5000;// u can change this .. here it is 5 seconds
    
            RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    
            queue.add(stringRequest);
    
        }
```

I deployed the sheet using this script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/DFJEKLE3LGsvate8vgAW72eDJQ_U/edit#gid=0");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Items'); // My sheet is named Items

function doPost(e){
var action = e.parameter.action;

if(action == 'addItem'){
  return addItem(e);
}
}

function addItem(e){
var code = e.parameter.Code;

sheet.appendRow([code]);
   return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Comment: For starters, `onErrorResponse` should actually do something. Otherwise, you are ignoring the errors from the server. Never assume your code will work correctly on the first try; write the error handling first